# Groovy delete specific file from the list

Tags: file, groovy

I try to delete files which i can find in `folderPath`. But I want delete only that, which have in name "Jenkins".
How to define in list to delete only that file.?

Example :
In C:\test\test have 3 files, want delete that which have Jenkins in name :

[image: Files]

```
import groovy.io.FileType

String folderPath = "C:\\test" + "\\" + "test"
def list = []
def dir = new File("$folderPath")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}
list.each {
println it.findAll() == "Jenkins" // Just files witch include in list "Jenkins" name
}
```

Thanks for tips !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

Use either of the below two:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

String folderPath = "C:/test/test"
new File(folderPath).eachFile (FileType.FILES) { file ->
//Delete file if file name contains Jenkins
   if (file.name.contains('Jenkins')) file.delete()
}
```

or

Below one uses `FileNameFinder` class

```
String folderPath = "C:/test/test"
def files = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(folderPath, '**/*Jenkins*')
println files
files.each { new File(it).delete()}
```

Comment: `file.path.contains('Jenkins')` is dangerous, you should use `file.name.contains('Jenkins')`. Imagine if `folderPath = "C:/Jenkins/test"`, you would delete all files in your loop.